# What is "full bi-section bandwidth" on AWS

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, bandwidth

Could somebody explain the concept "full bi-section bandwidth" in the context of AWS? I've seen the term mentioned in several places (Placement Groups, VPC peering). Say, I launch four c4.8xlarge (10 Gigabit network) - how does the "full bi-section bandwidth" affect me?

Comment: Please point us to the exact location where you're seeing this terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Normally bi-section bandwidth is used to describe the worst-case scenario of available bandwidth between network segments.

What I interpret this as saying is that these AWS instances (which are designed for HPC) have full bandwidth available to every other part of the AWS network.

i.e. you don't just have 10Gbps to the other nodes in your cluster, but 10Gbps to every part of your network.